# "import fuzzywuzzy" causes error, while "from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz" does not

Tags: python, import, fuzzywuzzy

When running the following code, I get an error message.

```
import fuzzywuzzy
print(fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.ratio('about', 'doubt'))
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vincent/Documents/PythonScripts/test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.ratio('about', 'doubt'))
AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'fuzz'
```

Howerer, the following runs perfectly.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
print(fuzz.ratio('about', 'doubt'))
```

Could someone help me solve this? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this depends on how your packages are laid out. I'm assuming that your directory tree looks something like this:

```
fuzzywuzzy/
           __init__.py
           fuzz.py
```

In that case, it's likely that `fuzz` is not imported in the `__init__.py` for `fuzzywuzzy`. When importing the top level of a module python only allows access to those things are imported into that module. Sub-modules require additional imports, as you've seen in your example.

If you want the first import to work then you'll need to add `import fuzz` to the `__init__.py` file for `fuzzywuzzy`, otherwise you'll have to use a `from ... import`. You could also `import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz`.

I would recommend not adding those imports to `__init__.py`, however, because it makes your code less explicit an means that new people reading the code will have to look through another file to understand from where functions are being imported.

Comment: To add to this you can see [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/749d61ab2ea35498c4d04d74dafde9248f253fb4/fuzzywuzzy/__init__.py) that the submodules are not imported in the `__init__.py`